# Extract value between HTML-tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I extract the value between the  tags (49% in message) using Javascript?
I will first parse the JSON with JSON.parse.

```
{
      "id": "189180337778229046", 
      "from": {
        "name": "My FB page", 
        "category": "Automobiles and parts", 
        "id": "189180337778229046"
      }, 
      "subject": "A good deal", 
      "message": "<p><strong>49%</strong></p><p>This is a good deal for you.</p>", 
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yY/r/d1gBp2bDGEuh.gif", 
      "created_time": "2011-11-02T10:49:56+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2011-11-02T10:49:56+0000"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple RegExp will do. Assume `obj` to hold the value of the parsed JSON string:

```
var percent = obj.message.match(/<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>/i)[1]; //Returns 49%
```

Comment: Will fail due to incomplete escaping (should be `<//strong>`).

Comment: I tried both <//strong> and </strong> and it fails (invalid flag).

Comment: @JonathanClark Inside an RegExp, characters have to be escaped using `\`. So, `<\/strong>`. Updated answer to correct mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest will be to use jQuery which looks like you're already using: (as `JSON.parse` is part of it)

```
var myValue = $(data.message).find("strong").eq(0).text();
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a new jQuery/DOM tree, so that jQuery methods can be used to perform a simple string operation? O_o

Comment: Yes, it's both more readable and flexible. The "price" for this is really minor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
var pattern = /([0-9]+%)/gi;
var result = obj.message.match(pattern);
```

This will only match integer numbers though..